# How to find the Z score of just one value?

Tags: python

I know the syntax of finding the z-score:

```
from scipy import stats
z = stats.zscore(a,axis = 0)
```

However, the value of that is accepted is in the form of an array. I just want the `Z-score` calculation of one value

My current code is:

```
import numpy as np

mean=100
sd=10
a = [(50-100)/10]
from scipy import stats
z = stats.zscore(a)
print(z)
```

I want the z-score of just a in the above code

Answer (score 1):

For finding cdf

```
scipy.stats.norm.cdf(1.64)
output : 0.9494974165258963
```

For finding z-score form cdf

```
ss.norm.ppf(0.9494974165258963)
output: 1.64
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mathematically impossible, because `stats.zscore` doesn't assume the input is normalized as you evidently think, but rather calculates the mean and standard deviation using the input. And SD of one value is zero which doesn't make sense.

But looks like you don't need any function to calculate your z-score, because it is by definition `(x - mean)/sd` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score), so you already have it in `a`. If you actually need something else, please write in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using cumulative distribution function (cdf).

```
scipy.stats.norm.cdf(1.64)
```

Returned value is 0.94949741652589625.

Meaning the Z-score value of 1.64 is 0.9495.

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

To follow along with what aparpara said, the `a` in your example is already the z-score.

It looks like you want to know how many standard deviations away is a sample value of 50. That is 5 sigma, as given by `a`.